# GetBuilder not updating on calling update()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to manage admob ads with GetBuilder but when I call update() after the ad loads. The GetBuilder is not updating.

My GetBuilder:

```
 GetBuilder<AdManager>(
                    init: AdManager()..createAnchoredBanner(context),
                    builder: (aM) {
                      if (aM.anchoredBanner != null)
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          width: aM.anchoredBanner!.size.width.toDouble(),
                          height: aM.anchoredBanner!.size.height.toDouble(),
                          child: AdWidget(ad: aM.anchoredBanner!),
                        );
                      return Container();
                    },
                  )
```

My Controller function:

```
Future<void> createAnchoredBanner(BuildContext context) async {
    print("Banner");
    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size =
        await AdSize.getAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
      Orientation.landscape,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate(),
    );

    if (size == null) {
      print('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }

    final BannerAd banner = BannerAd(
      size: size,
      request: request,
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('$BannerAd loaded.');
          anchoredBanner = ad as BannerAd?;
          update(); // This is not working
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('$BannerAd failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdOpened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('$BannerAd onAdClosed.'),
      ),
    );
    await banner.load();
  }
```

It always shows Blank container even if I call update().

I am using same pattern in all of my apps and I never faced such issue. Please help.